# JsonGenerator : unwanted double quote

Tags: java, html, json, playframework, jackson

I am using Jackson to create json object and then return them to the client, whether using ajax or as an attribute value in the Html dom.

This is how I create my json string :

```
public void             serialize(Customer comp, JsonGenerator gen)
{
    gen.writeStartObject();
    gen.writeObjectField("idCustomer", comp.idCustomer);
    gen.writeObjectField("name", "\"" + comp.infos.nameCompany + "\"");
    gen.writeEndObject();
}
```

The problem is that the result of this function is different wether it is used in html or in ajax. It look like once, jackson detect comp.infos.nameCompany as beeing a string, and the others, it doesn't.
The ajax version :

```
"customer": {"idCustomer": 1,"name": "cu1"}
```

When this json string is in html :

```
"customer": {"idCustomer": 1,"name": "\"cu1\""}
```

Note the unwanted \" in the html version.

Why this difference and how to avoid it ?
Thanks.

**Edit:** @Salem

This is the code where I implement the json in the html. This is a play framowork template code :

```
<div content="@structure.getContent">
</div>
```

Comment: Please add the code part where you print that value in your html page.

Comment: Try to use `@Html(structure.getContent)` instead

Comment: @Salem thanks, but it doesn't solved the problem.

Comment: And `gen.writeStringField("name", comp.infos.nameCompany);` instead of `writeObjectField` ?

Comment: @Salem The writeStringField function writes its arguments as a string and escape all of the characters. The result is something like this : "customer": "{\"idCustomer\": 1,\"name\": \"\"cu1\"\"}". It's not even an object. Thanks anyway for keeping helping me.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/60184/discussion-between-salem-and-moebius).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution was to use the writeStringField method instead of writeObjectField :

```
public class JsonCustomerSerializer extends JsonSerializer<Customer>
{
    @Override
    public void serialize(Customer comp, JsonGenerator gen, SerializerProvider provider)throws IOException, JsonProcessingException
    {
        gen.writeStartObject();
        gen.writeObjectField("idCustomer", comp.idCustomer);
        gen.writeStringField("name", comp.infos.nameCompany);
        gen.writeEndObject();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Remove `"\""` totally and see what happens. If I remember doing this correctly it should work as you want. If the value of `comp.infos.nameCompany` is of type String it should add quotes automatically

Answer (score 0):

@Lucas
Thanks for your help, but comp.infos.nameCompany is a string.

If I remove the + "\"", the html version is correct :

```
"customer": {"idCustomer": 1,"name": "cu1"}
```

But now the ajax version is :

```
"customer": {"idCustomer": 1,"name": cu1}
```

It is not even a correct json.
Whatever I ever there is one more double quote in the html version.

Comment: or maybe try replacing `"\""` with `'` (single quote) (if single quotes suitable for you). If not I'm out of ideas.

Comment: @Lucas Using single quote is not the solution. Thanks anyway.